# Como contar quantas substrings tem em uma string em C?

Tags: c, string

https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2126

Esse exercício eu achei melhor ler como string ou não...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
char N1,quantidadesdeN1;

while(scanf("%s",&N1)!=EOF)
   {
     scanf("%s",&quantidadesdeN1);

     /*Como faço pra ver quantos N1 tem na variável quantidadesdeN1 com strcmp ?No strcmp tem jeito de pegar apenas partes da quantidadedeN1? Se caso não for possível resolver no strcmp tem outro jeito de resolver ?
     */
   }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

na biblioteca  você tem uma função que se chama
strncmp(str1, str2, numero_de_casas)

str1 => variável 1
str2 => variável 2
numero_de_casas => você colocar quantas casas deseja para comparação.

Coloque a função em um laço de repetição, que vai modificando a posição inicial da str2, uma variável de contagem para as vezes que foram encontradas a str1, e por fim uma variável para primeira posição

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncmp.htm

Comment: Eu tive que usar o strlen() para contar números de casas. Na hora do laço como vou fazer vou fazer para mudar a posição inicial de str2 ?

Comment: Quando você chama str2 (ou o nome da variável string) você na verdade está fazendo referência a posição str2[0] e a rotina lê quantas casas além forem necessarias, se você colocar str2+1 você estará fazendo referência a str2[1], então use a variável de controle de repetição para ir aumentando a posição que deseja começar

Comment: Não consigo entender...#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
char N1[10],quantidadesdeN1[30];

while(scanf("%s",&N1)!=EOF)
   {
     int cont = strlen(N1),i,subsequencias=0;
     
     
     
     scanf("%s",&quantidadesdeN1);
     
     int cont2 = strlen(quantidadesdeN1);
     
     for(i=0; i<cont2; i++)
     {
  
      if(strncmp(N1,quantidadesdeN1[i],cont)==0)
      subsequencias++
     
     }
     
     

   
   }

 return(0);  
}

Comment: Coloque quantidadesdeN1+i ao invez de quantidadesdeN1[i], pois da sua forma ele está apenas pegandl um caracter, da primeira forma ela diz que a string inicia de quantidadesdeN1[0] e no próximo ciclo inicia de quantidadesdeN1[1]

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar a função [strstr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm), essa função verifica a existência de uma substring em uma string, depois é só contar o numero de caracteres que tem na substring comparando com a string,  ou tambem a função [strncmp()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncmp.htm)

Caso seja para verificar so a partir do inicio, Ex:

```
112
1125468
```

Nesse caso poderá fazer um ciclo e percorrer caracter a caracter, caso seja diferente dê um `break` e conclui que não é Subsequência

Vai ser preciso tambem alocar memoria de `10^10` e `10^32` nas 2 strings, como pede o exercicio.

[Codigo](https://ideone.com/LgXpBd):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char N1[100], N2[100];
    int count=0, x=0;

    scanf(" %s",N1);
    scanf(" %s", N2);
    do
    {
        if(!strncmp(N2+x, N1, strlen(N1)))
        {
            count++;
            printf("N1 e´ uma substring de N2\n");
            printf("Qtd.Subsequencias %d\n", count);
            x+=strlen(N1);
        }
        else
            x+=1;
    }    while(x<strlen(N2));

}
```

Penso que seja isso que você quer fazer, obviamente que temos de tirar os prints no ciclo, porem é so um exemplo

STDIN

```
12
123123123123
```

STDOUT

```
N1 e´ uma substring de N2
Qtd.Subsequencias 4
```

Como podemos verificar, na ultima iteração Qtd.Subsequencias é igual a 4.
Neste caso a forma mais rapida seria usar a função [strncmp()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncmp.htm)

Comment: Eu entendi como funciona a função strstr(), mas como vou fazer esse laço e contar? quantas substring tem na string...

Comment: @Misaee21 Vou editar a minha resposta com o codigo que fiz, por favor confira.

Comment: Está meio diferente das respostas lá do site teste esta entrada. STDIN 12 STDOUT 1231321455123214565423112

Comment: @Misaee21 Tem razao, ja vou editar com a solução correta

Comment: Consegui resolver, mas tive usar a função que o cara indicou ali em baixo... se quiser ver meu código é só falar.

Comment: @Misaee21 Eu já tinha editado a minha resposta com essa soluçao

Comment: Não entendi, você já fez?

Comment: @Misaee21 Veja o código que está na minha resposta à sua pergunta, faz exatamente o pedido, eu tinha editado e colocado um codigo melhorado